# Input Masking using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I need to input masking for this format

**HTML**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateTime, true, 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control datetimeMask",
            @maxlength = "20", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
                model.DateTime) })
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".datetimeMask").inputmask({
    mask: "2/1/y h:s t\\m",
    placeholder: "YYYYMMDD-HHMMTT",
    alias: "datetime",
    hourFormat: "12",
});
```

Comment: any error you're getting?

Comment: format is YYYYMMDD-HHMMTT